# django database router cannot import name connection

Tags: python, database, django

i have issue with the DB Router on Django 1.4 (python 2.6). I have follow the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) but when i run my server i have this following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing database router MyDBRouter: "cannot import name connection"
```

My settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'other' : {
        ...
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['core.models.MyDBRouter',]
```

here the db router code :

```
class MyAppRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation if a model in myapp is involved"
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'myapp' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the myapp app only appears on the 'other' db"
        if db == 'other':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'myapp'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return False
        return None
```

I have try to replace None by 'default' but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you shown all code of _core.models_ ? There might be _connection_  referenced/imported in it.

Comment: yes, this is the whole models.py file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this probleme by adding "from django.db import connections" on settings.py

```
151 # Database router                                                                                                                                       
152 from django.db import connections
153 DATABASE_ROUTERS         = ['core.models.MyDBRouter',]
```

Now the server run fine! But router is just IGNORED by django -> To fix it, never save Router in models !  create new file

Comment: Alright, for future wanderers: this is likely a circular import issue.  If you have anything that imports Django modules in your __init__.py file in the same module as your router, you will have issues.  So I simply moved the code in my __init__.py file to another module and imported from there.

Answer (score 1):

That did no good to me, I posted my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17888067/978912, maybe it can save someone the pain of debugging through endless import chains. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like `Zakum` is saying in his solution,

if the above mentioned solutions don't work for you, see if you did an import

```
from django.db.models import Model
```

in any of your routing-files. If so, you have to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was coded in the `__init__.py` file of one of my apps. I think init files are direct dependencies of the `settings.py` file, and this may lead to cyclic imports.