# Django 1.5 : 'Error importing database router' that was previously importing correctly

Tags: django, django-settings

I'm running Django 1.5 for the last several weeks developing an app with multiple databases. I set up a router for a separate database an placed it under routers.py in my project directory in settings I made sure to add the path to the router the way the django documentation dictates:

```
# Extra Database Routing modules
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routers.MyRouter']
```

And that worked. For the last 2 weeks there have been no issues. Now, randomly after I saved my models.py file after taking out an `from djanog.conf import settings` that was not being used, I got this on my development server after running `python manage.py runserver`:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
August 02, 2013 - 16:12:42
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'app.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing database router MyRouter: "cannot import name connection"
```

Note that it validated all the models before erroring. Which didn't make any sense to me.
I went to these places seeking an answer

- [django 1.4 database router - "cannot import name connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711536/django-1-4-database-router-cannot-import-name-connection)
- [Django multi-database routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054195/django-multi-database-routing/17888067#17888067)
- [django database router cannot import name connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452837/django-database-router-cannot-import-name-connection)

The attempts at importing connections with `from django.db import connections` inside my settings file, resulting in causing an `ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.` That's simply because when importing `connections` it also imports everything inside the django.db `__init__.py` which includes `from django.conf import settings` which then overwrites the settings I already had. (or at least I believe that's what's happening) Point being is that something is happening which I don't fully understand.

Can anyone shed some light on why suddenly my router would be unable to be imported?

Comment: After some few hours of powering over the core django files there appears to be a circular import which is actually a bug inside the Django framework that is fixed for 1.6: here's the ticket <https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20704>

Moving my routers.py containing my custom router which was in my project directory to a different module (I used the app module which doesn't have any \__init__.py file) made everything run correctly again.

Hope this saves some one some headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some few hours of powering over the core django files there appears to be a circular import which is actually a bug inside the Django framework that is fixed for 1.6: here's the ticket <[code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20704](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20704)>; Moving my routers.py containing my custom router which was in my project directory to a different module (I used the app module which doesn't have any *init*.py file) made everything run correctly again. Hope this saves some one some headaches.

Comment: Thanks! My router was placed in models module. I moved them to the personal module in a same app. Solved!