# Django: Manage.py runserver no error, but mod_wsgi report cannot import name connection

Tags: django, deployment, import, wsgi

When testing my django website by `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, there is no error.

But if I deploy it to production with apache and mod_wsgi, it reports error `cannot import name connection`.

I find some other questions like [django 1.4 database router - "cannot import name connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711536/django-1-4-database-router-cannot-import-name-connection) suggesting adding `from django.db import connections` into settings.py.

But I found adding this import can prevent this error, but it also disables database router.

I think it may due to different running environment between `manage.py runserver` and WSGI.
This is how my wsgi.py looks like

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"/home/my/myweb")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mywebsite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

How can I fix this bug?

My python version is 2.7 and django version is 1.4.3

**Edit 1:**

My OS is CentOS 6.4, on this server:

If I run it using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, no error.

If I remove database router, it can work under WSGI.

But database router and WSGI cannot work together.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit 2:**

Thanks to @Graham Dumpleton, I figured it out by myself.

This is the wsgy.py that works for me.

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/my/myweb')

from mywebsite import settings

import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)
utility = django.core.management.ManagementUtility()
command = utility.fetch_command('runserver')

command.validate()

import django.conf
import django.utils

django.utils.translation.activate(django.conf.settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: what is your operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually caused by using a mix of imports where some imports are via the site package and some don't. You can add:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/home/my/myweb/mywebsite")
```

and that may help.

For a bit of a discussion of the problem see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html