# Setting models to specific database in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I would like to ask how to set models to specific database .
I'm still new to django and read about the [Database Routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) in the Django website,  I have 2 models, `userMod` and `adminMod`.
`userMod` should go to database **userDB**.
`adminMod` should go to database **adminDB**.
But when I migrated it, both table exist in both database.
I already have included `app_label` on meta, but its still not working.
I am using django 1.8

---

EDIT:
I am just trying it on userDB for a while and eventually will use it with adminDB.
This is my code:

routers.py

```
class router(object):

def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == 'userDB':
        return 'userDB'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.app_label == 'userDB':
        return 'userDB'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'userDB' or\
        obj2._meta.app_label == 'userDB':
            return True
        return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
    if app_label == 'userDB':
        return db == 'userDB'
    return None
```

Comment: Hi, please insert your code for more clarity. Read this to improve your question so that we can help you better. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could you paste the code of your database router?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class userMod(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

   class Meta:
      db_table='userDB'
```

Comment: Hi @Geo Jacob. Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately this didn't work. Both tables still exist in `userDB`

Comment: I didn't tried this, but this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547468/multiple-databases-and-multiple-models-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Remember to tell django about your database router in the settings.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/

Search for DATABASE_ROUTERS setting