# define database modelwise in django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I just tried to find a solution for define database model wise in Django.
like in my settings.py there are three databases

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db_one': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_one.sqlite3'),
    },
    'db_two': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db_two.sqlite3'),
    },
}
```

And in my polls/models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

now I want to add question model in db_one database and Choice model in db_two database so how can I do that

I try with routers follow this [multiple databases and multiple models in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547468/multiple-databases-and-multiple-models-in-django)
but it prefers only default database only after that I tried with put the blank setting in default database and try to migrate but it gives me an error

or

is that way to define a database for application wise in Django

Answer (score 0):

you can use database my `using` method.

For example, fetching all data from `db_one` would look like:

`all_data = YourModel.objects.using('db_one').all()`

Comment: fetching data is coming later in the picture first I just want to create that table to database wise the problem is I am not able to migrate that table(create table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your model to a database other than the default, right?

You can select the database while migrating.

```
# database name from settings.py
./manage.py migrate --database=<database-name>
```

[django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/)

If you want to keep some tables in one database and some tables in other databases, I suggest to create a migration per table. Then, you will be able to run

```
./manage.py migrate <your-app-name> <migration-number> --database=<database-name>
```

**EDIT**

You can skip the creation of a specific table in a specific database with `--fake` flag.

- first, remove all of your migrations.
- comment out your `Choice` model in `models.py`.
- run `manage.py makemigrations` => suppose this created migration `001` (for `Question` model)
- uncomment you `Choice` model in  `models.py`.
- run `manage.py makemigrations` again. suppose this created migration `002` (for `Choice` model)
- run `manage.py migrate <app-name> 001 --database=db_one` => this will create Question model in db_one
- run `manage.py migrate <app-name> 001 --database=db_two --fake` => this
  will skip the creation of the table in db_two
- run `python manage.py migrate <app-name> 002 --database=db_one --fake`
  => this will skip the creation of the Choice table in db_one
- run `python manage.py migrate <app-name> 002 --database=db_two` => this will create Choice model in db_two.

Comment: no, I want to use the separate model of one app when I migrate table so it will create only default databases

Comment: what do you mean by separate? keeping copies of the tables in different databases?

Comment: no, i don't want to create a copy of Question model is only create in db_one and a Choice table is only create in db_two no in default or any other database

Comment: ok, then, as I pointed in the second part, you need to create a migration per each model. Then, run migrations on databases selectively. I will update my answer to show how you can skip the creating of a table on a specific database. actually you need to use --fake option for this.