# Python django adding multiple database

Tags: django, database, model

How to create or add multiple databases in django.
Where always my models are created in default database .how to change it

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I dint tried any. I'm blank in switching dbs

Comment: Have you tried [Google searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+django+create+multiple+databases&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS770US770&oq=python+django+create+multiple+databases&aqs=chrome..69i57.6344j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Tried googling....but dint get proper answer

Comment: Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547468/multiple-databases-and-multiple-models-in-django) I found. Maybe this can help a little...

Comment: I too saw those answers.its about switching in between dbs but they didn't say how to create 1

Comment: Hmm, maybe [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/) from the Django documentation.

Comment: It says ... If you attempt to access a database that you haven’t defined in your DATABASES setting, Django will raise a django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist exception

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation has good reference on this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Once you define the databases a new database other than 'default', you can use

```
$ ./manage.py migrate --database=new_database_name
```

for performing the migration or table creation

Comment: Yeah I saw those things....in my project,user wants to create a new database every time. Where in cannot cannot add those databases every time in settings...