# Multiple databases in django - syncdb doesn't create django_ tables

Tags: django, django-syncdb

I'm facing a problem when using multiple databases in Django.

Here's the scenario:

I have a django project, which is divided into two applications: `app1` and `app2`. `App1` will take care of authentication and custom modules (ie. it has its own `models.py`) and `App2` is normal web application (ie. it has its own `models.py` with models in it).

Settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app1.router.AuthRouter', 'app1.router.App1Router', 'app2.router.App2Router']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
      [...]
    },
    'app2': {
      [...]
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have two databases (both PSQL 9.2), `default` (used for `app1` application) and `app2` (used for `app2` application) and I've defined such 3 routers (1. for authentification, 2. for `app1 model` and last for `app2 model`.

Code for `app1.router.AuthRouter` and `app1.router.App1Router` is following:

```
class AuthRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
                    return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
                    return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'default':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'auth'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return False
        return None


class App1Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
                    return 'default'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
                    return 'default'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'app1' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'default':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'app1'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return False
        return None
```

Problem is that, when I do `syncdb`, it does correctly create `auth_` tables, but it does not create `django_` tables, which fails in error.

```
[marek@t420 multipledb_test]$ python manage.py syncdb 
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  [more errors coming]
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
```

YOU SEE? THERE ARE NO DJANGO TABLES CREATED - no `django_admin_log`, no `django_content_type`, no `django_session`!!!

Any hints? It's driving me crazy for three days!

Comment: Using multiple databases in Django is problematical at best, as you've found.  I discovered myself in a similar situation earlier this year, and the least time-consuming and most effective solution was to implement a database join migration script.

Comment: Do you mean using just one database, which is shared between all applications?
If it was possible, I'd love to use just 1 postgres DB with different schemas inside (1 for each application), but it doesn't work.
I truly need application data separated. Whole idea is create a web portal (`default app` as a wrapper with all users, passwords etc) and other apps will be added 'independently' (`app2` is actually attendance system, `app3` a ticket system ...)
Any Ideas?

Comment: Need to clarify some terminology for me... are you referring to multiple applications within the same Django project, or multiple projects themselves?

Comment: Well, as far as i know, two django projects can't speak to each other. That's why I wanted to create one Django project, which will have different applications inside (default app1, app2 - web attendance, app3 - ticket system, ...).
I want to have the system as independent as possible, but these parts (app1, app2, app3) have to be able to communicate (actually app2, app3 have to authenticate using app1) - which led me to use 1 Django projects with multiple apps(each having own database). Is is clear?

Comment: Understood.  Another user had a similar problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054195/django-multi-database-routing and documented the process at http://djangosteps.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/multiple-database-implementation-in-django/  Its somewhat old, but may help.

Answer (score 3):

Just a comment:
My idea was to use a few databases, which will communicate within each other (eg. using Foreign keys from one DB to another one).
I wish i read the documentation more carefully:

> Cross-database relations
>   Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases. If you have used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be internal to a single database.

All that mess was for nothing, because integrity constraints dont allow to use any relationships over multiple databases.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me is this post:
http://diegobz.net/2011/02/10/django-database-router-using-settings/

Solution is this:

1. using just one Router, and this router will take care of application 2 - router `app2.router.App2Router`,not any routers for default database. Routers for default database works fine just as it is.
2. Alter that `app2.router.App2Router` to look like the code in that link in the beginning of the post provided. Doing just step 1 led to creating `auth_` and `django_` tables (by running `syncdb`) correctly, but unfortunately ALL MODEL tables were created to default database (ie. also tables from `app2`). Altering `app2.router.App2Router` made everything work.
3. Alter `settings.py` to look like this:

   DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app2.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']

   DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'app2': 'app2'}

Now running `syncdb database=app2` creates tables to database `app2` and running `syncdb` creates all django system tables and own `app1` tables to `default`. Awesome!

Thanks Jason for his ideas!

Comment: I'm still having this same problem.