# Django multiple dynamic databases after server startup

Tags: python, django, database

I'm new to django and try to figure out what would be the best solution for me to use dynamically multiple databases in django.
I know django is able to work with multiple databases registered in the settings.py file but In my case I have one main database (sqlite) which acts as my repository, I created all the models, the rest api viewsets for this one.

The user can choose to connect to an Oracle database by entering the connection information and then I will need to gather data from this database and insert it to my repository. The user can register multiple Oracle databases through the app. I'm wondering if I should use a pure cx_Oracle class to handle those connection from django or if I should register them in the settings.py?

Each view in the frontend maps to a specific database and I will need to switch context between them, If I use a cx_Oracle class how can I route the requests to the right class instance in the backend?

Any help or insight would be appreciated, I didn't find anything matching my use case on the internet.

Comment: Doesn't [this article](http://sligodave.com/dynamic-databases-and-models-in-django-EN.html) describe exactly what you need?

Comment: What about routing? That is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054195/django-multi-database-routing)

Comment: @hoefling This is excatly what I need, I don't know why I wasn't able to find it.
If you write and answer I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski it's a part of it but not the complete puzzle.
Thanks both of you

Comment: Ok, but let me write something in there so the answer is not completely useless...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As found out in the comments - [here](http://sligodave.com/dynamic-databases-and-models-in-django-EN.html) is an article describing how to set up a server instance with selecting databases on the fly, so its author is the one that should get all credits. Restating the basic approach:

1. Create a model class representing the db connection:

   ```
   class Database(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
       config = JSONField()
   ```
2. Add a `label` property to distinct the db connection entities. Here, it requires to set strings `DYNAMIC_DATABASES_PREFIX` and `DYNAMIC_DATABASES_SEPARATOR` in the django settings, but could also be hardcoded as some constants:

   ```
   class Database(models.Model):
       ...
       @property
       def label(self):
           # We want to be able to identify the dynamic databases and apps
           # So we prepend their names with a common string
           prefix = getattr(settings, 'DYNAMIC_DATABASES_PREFIX', 'DYNAMIC_DATABASE')
           separator = getattr(settings, 'DYNAMIC_DATABASES_SEPARATOR', '_')
           return '{}{}{}'.format(prefix, separator, self.pk)
   ```
3. Add a method for adding the db connection to/removing the db connection from django's db connections (the nifty part is putting a dummy app for each db connection - this way we can have different databases with duplicate table names):

   ```
   class Database(models.Model):
       ...
       def register(self):
           # label for the database connection and dummy app
           label = self.label
           # Do we have this database registered yet
           if label not in connections._databases:
               # Register the database
               connections._databases[label] = self.config
               # Break the cached version of the database dict so it'll find our new database
               del connections.databases
           # Have we registered our fake app that'll hold the models for this database
           if label not in apps.app_configs:
               # We create our own AppConfig class, because the Django one needs a path to the module that is the app.
               # Our dummy app obviously doesn't have a path
               AppConfig2 = type('AppConfig'.encode('utf8'),(AppConfig,),
                                 {'path': '/tmp/{}'.format(label)})
               app_config = AppConfig2(label, label)
               # Manually register the app with the running Django instance
               apps.app_configs[label] = app_config
               apps.app_configs[label].models = {}

       def unregister(self):
           label = self.label
           if label in apps.app_configs:
               del apps.app_configs[label]
           if label in apps.all_models:
               del apps.all_models[label]
           if label in connections._databases:
               del connections._databases[label]
               del connections.databases
   ```
4. Add a connection lookup by connection name that also registers the connection to running django instance, making it operational:

   ```
   class Database(models.Model):
       ...
       def get_model(self, table_name):
           # Ensure the database connect and it's dummy app are registered
           self.register()
           label = self.label
           model_name = table_name.lower().replace('_', '')

           # Is the model already registered with the dummy app?
           if model_name not in apps.all_models[label]:
               # Use the "inspectdb" management command to get the structure of the table for us.
               file_obj = StringIO()
               Command(stdout=file_obj).handle(database=label, table_name_filter=lambda t: t == table_name)
               model_definition = file_obj.getvalue()
               file_obj.close()

               # Make sure that we found the table and have a model definition
               loc = model_definition.find('(models.Model):')
               if loc != -1:
                   # Ensure that the Model has a primary key.
                   # Django doesn't support multiple column primary keys,
                   # So we have to add a primary key if the inspect command didn't
                   if model_definition.find('primary_key', loc) == -1:
                       loc = model_definition.find('(', loc + 14)
                       model_definition = '{}primary_key=True, {}'.format(model_definition[:loc + 1], model_definition[loc + 1:])
                   # Ensure that the model specifies what app_label it belongs to
                   loc = model_definition.find('db_table = \'{}\''.format(table_name))
                   if loc != -1:
                       model_definition = '{}app_label = \'{}\'\n        {}'.format(model_definition[:loc], label, model_definition[loc:])

                   # Register the model with Django. Sad day when we use 'exec'
                   exec(model_definition, globals(), locals())
                   # Update the list of models that the app
                   # has to match what Django now has for this app
                   apps.app_configs[label].models = apps.all_models[label]
               else:
                   logger.info('Could not find table: %s %s', label, table_name)
           else:
               logger.info('Already added dynamic model: %s %s', label, table_name)

           # If we have the connection, app and model. Return the model class
           if (label in connections._databases and label in apps.all_models and model_name in apps.all_models[label]):
               return apps.get_model(label, model_name)
   ```
5. Create custom db routing, using the mentioned config strings for db selection:

   ```
   class DynamicDatabasesRouter(object):
       label_prefix = '{}{}'.format(
           getattr(settings, 'DYNAMIC_DATABASES_PREFIX', 'DYNAMIC_DATABASE'),
           getattr(settings, 'DYNAMIC_DATABASES_SEPARATOR', '_')
       )

       def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
           if model._meta.app_label.startswith(self.label_prefix):
               # We know that our app_label matches the database connection's name
               return model._meta.app_label
           return None

       def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
           if model._meta.app_label.startswith(self.label_prefix):
               # We know that our app_label matches the database connection's name
               return model._meta.app_label
           return None

       def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
           return None

       def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
           return None
   ```
6. Register the router in settings:

   ```
   DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp.routing.DynamicDatabasesRouter']
   ```
7. (Optional) make the model modifiable in the admin site if you use it:

   ```
   def config(conn):
       return json.dumps(conn.config)
   config.short_description = 'Config'

   class DatabaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('name', config)

   admin.site.register(Database, DatabaseAdmin)
   ```

An example usage in a view:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data()

        # We can pick which dynamic database connection we want based on a GET parameter
        db = Database.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('env', 1))
        # Pass the database instance to the template so we can display it.
        context['db'] = db

        # Get a model class for a table in our dynamic database.
        # Lets pretend there's a table called 'author'
        Author = db.get_model('author')
        authors = Author.objects.all().order_by('name')
        # Send the author instances to the template for iterating over.
        context['authors'] = authors

        return context
```

Comment: I have one more question, in the register function we have the following line:
apps.app_configs[label].models = {}
So the models are always empty which makes the get_model to always try to do an inspect_db. How can I register models correctly

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO how did you fix this ? I'm facing the same problem, my get_model function is trying to run inspect_db , do I need to have abstract classes for those models  or what?

Comment: Mentioned link is down.
Here is the snapshot from archive.org
https://web.archive.org/web/20180819153157/https://sligodave.com/dynamic-databases-and-models-in-django-EN.html