# How to use django on two databases

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-contrib

I have a legacy Django project with a legacy database. That project uses django.contrib.auth.User as the user model. Now I need to write a new Django project and that app has to get access to the legacy database. The problem is that my new Django project also needs a User object. So how do I route django.contrib.auth.user models into the correct database?

Another possible way to do this: is it possible to "bootstrap" a Django app for use inside another project? So if I have a legacy Django app with legacy settings.py, and I want to use the Django model functionality inside a new Django project with new settings.py (and it has its own apps), is there a way to do this?

Comment: use `db-routers`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi-database routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054195/django-multi-database-routing)